# Buying Product on Time from Online Store - Drupal, Joomla, Wordpress?

Tags: content-management-system, e-commerce

Does anyone know of a plugin or the like for any of the popular CMS that allow a customer to buy a product on time?

For example: the product costs $500. The customer can put a deposit down, and pay $100 a month for the next 4 months.

Thanks

Comment: you can achieve this by implementing recurring payments.

Comment: @Kishore recurring payments with Drupal? Where at? Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvote? If it belongs elsewhere, admin could move it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I have found a viable solution to this is to have a recurring setup option set with the CC processing company. The user agrees they will be pay $X twice or four times and the processor bills the card X times. It needs to be handled by the processor in order to stay away from storing CC info in your db.